# react-native not generating file for android

Tags: react-native

I'm probably reading about this issues for more than a couple of hours and I cannot find anything that could be useful.
I'm quite new in react-native and everything was fine until I installed this package:
react-native-popup-dialog

After that, I started to get errors and then, I removed the the package using the npm uninstall command. The error suggested:

```
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
```

Well, I made this and now I cannot make the project work again. I'm getting this error:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
Bundling `index.android.js`
  Transforming modules  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░  86.0% (575/620)...(node:12608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1626): UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module react-native/Libraries/Components/StaticContainer.react from D:\Code\Mobile\node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\Tabs\SceneComponent.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  D:\Code\Mobile\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
(node:12608) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process Bundling `index.android.js`
```

I do understand about not finding the module StaticContainer.react, but I didn't made anything in the Native-base. I tried again to remove the node_modules and clean-cache, but didn't work.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.0.10",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.43.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^0.1.29",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.7.22",
    "react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks,
Joao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Native-base team changed the dependencies from:
`"react": "^15.4.2"` to `"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.3"`
and
`"react-native": "^0.39.2"` to `"react-native": "^0.43.0"`

When you reinstalled Native-base by performing `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` it probably installed the newer code base with the above mentioned changes.

So either you update to the newer versions or, if you can't upgrade because about other dependencies, make changes manually in the module folder:

Open `SceneComponent.js` in `~/node_modules/native-base/dist/src/basic/Tabs/`

and change line 6 from

`var StaticContainer=require('react-native/Libraries/Components/StaticContainer.react');`

to

`var StaticContainer=require('react-native/Libraries/Components/StaticContainer');`

Don't forget to perform a `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: Nice, I made the correct updates and worked like a charm. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome. Please keep in mind that the second option is just a quick fix. Eventually you need to update all your libraries one-by-one. ;-)